# Creating a Java web service client

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, apache-axis

Last few days I searched all over the internet to solve this problem  but I couldn't solve this yet. The problem is this.I have a simple web service implemented in Eclipse Indigo as follow

```
package com.testvtfour.ws;

public class Customer {

private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

Web service part is perfect. I used Axis2 as soap engine & Tomcat 7 as the server. Problem occurs when I'm trying to consume this web service. I created web service client in eclipse & Axis2 Automatically generats "CusstomerCallBackHandler" & "CustomerStub". Following is the implemented client

```
package com.testvtfour.ws;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import com.testvtfour.ws.CustomerStub.SetName;
import com.testvtfour.ws.CustomerStub.GetNameResponse;
public class TestClient {
public static void main(String[] args)throws RemoteException{
    CustomerStub stub = new CustomerStub();
    com.testvtfour.ws.CustomerStub.SetName obj = new 
        com.testvtfour.ws.CustomerStub.SetName();
    obj.setName("Grant");
    stub.setName(obj);

    com.testvtfour.ws.CustomerStub.GetNameResponse res = stub.getName();
    System.out.println(res.get_return());
}
}
```

But always this prints "null". Why is that? How can I solve this? & I want to know that the updated value by this kind of client can be showed in an Android application. Because It is second part of my project. Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you read this one: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients-xmlbeans.html and are you sure the result should be in `get_return()`?

Comment: I believe a web service is typically stateless. This means the `get` is called on a different instance than the `set` was called on, hence `name` is null. You can check if this is the issue by changing `return name;` into `return "hello";`

Comment: I'm not sure about the result should be in get_return(). I used one of eclipse solutions. What I should use there???

Comment: When using return hello; it prints the string correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Axis2 web service is typically stateless. This means that the `getName()` is called on a different instance than the `setName()` was called on, hence `name` is null when you try to retrieve it.

- See [Axis2 Session Management](http://www.developer.com/services/article.php/3620661/Axis2-Session-Management.htm) on how to deal with sessions.
- See this SO question and its answers: [Axis2 Session Managment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646414/axis2-session-managment)

Comment: Can you please explain how should I invoke getName() ??

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your client; it is just the web service 'showing a new face' every time you call it. If you want `getName` to return the parameter of the previous `setName`, then you have to make the service remember the name, either using session management or just by storing it into something persistent like a database or a plain text file.

Comment: Thank you!! & One thing I want to know... can I access MySQL data base using android application successfully??

Comment: That's another question. Typically you would access MySQL from the web service (the server) not from the android application (the client). I suggest you do some more research on that.